# Sticker Pack Interface Builder Storyboard Compiler Error Group

Tags: ios, xcode, imessage, ios10

WWDC 2016 came up with a new concept of creating Sticker Pack & push it to store from iOS10 onwards. I downloaded XCode 8 Beta, & tried to create a sticker pack app for the message extensions.

I did everything as explained but on building the project I am getting error

> Interface Builder Storyboard Compiler Error Group

Strange thing is for Sticker Pack we don't need to write any code, but still it is showing error of Interface Builder.

I am getting this error under build time

[image: IB Error]

I have also reported this to apple, but would like to know if anyone has any idea to remove this & execute my code.

Comment: I have this bug on my mac mini, but the same project on macbook is builded correct.

Comment: @HDmast I am trying on macbook itself & still facing the same issue. I have also tried on another macbook & same issue persist.

Comment: Do you try rename xcode, clean project and delete derived data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

When you will download the Xcode-beta & when you will unzip the .xip file, the xcode-beta will present in same folder where the min file is downloaded, strange thing is that apple is not automatically pushing xcode-beta to Application folder.

If you are experiencing the same issue, push the xcode-beta executable to `Applications` folder, & execute your project from there & you will find that it will work like charm.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I rename application `xcode-beta` to `xcode 8.0b` in finder. After what IDE cann't open any xib and storyboard.
Solution: don't rename app.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you

Comment: @iYoung, check xcode application name in finder. It should be called `Xcode-beta`

Comment: Yes, it is xcode beta & I renamed it as well. Still no luck :(

Comment: Maybe some problem with localization on your mac or move xcode app in another folder. I think problem in path to application.

Comment: @iYoung, I found: "Note: If you have enabled “Open ‘safe’ files after downloading” in Safari Preferences, the XIP file downloads and is automatically expanded in your download file folder. Drag Xcode-beta to the Applications folder before launching it".

Answer (score -1):

Got it working finally. In my case, Xcode was there in the Applications folder, but for some reason it was named "Xcode-beta 2". Renamed it to "Xcode-beta", restarted the application, cleared derived data, and it started working.